# Adding GWT-EXT Button on toolbar displayed differently than to add it on a panel

Tags: gwt-ext

I want to know that when i add a GWT-EXT button to the toolbar it appears as if it were a link,you can see the border is not visible and it just got blended with the toolbar .

[image: Image1]

However when add the same button to the panel it viewed  properly.

[image: Image2]

I just want the button when it is added to to toolbar of a panel to be exactly similar when it is added to a panel.

Answer (score 0):

go the that button and write listener,

```
    listeners: {
        render: function() {
            this.addCls("x-btn-default-small");
            this.removeCls("x-btn-default-toolbar-small");
        }
    }
```

This will resolve your problem